# Can I combine Comment field from other Parameters in Altium Designer?

Tags: pcb-design, altium

Comment can be set from Parameter like =Parameter:

```
=Value
```

where Value can be set as 100nF for example [Comment Properties](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/Sch_Prop-Comment((Comment+Properties))_AD).

Can I combine several individual parameters into Comment? to get something like:

```
100nF; 16V
```

I tried following

```
=Value; =Voltage
```

and it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following special string format in your comment field to do what you want:

`=Parameter1+'; '+Parameter2`

Below are some images of the setup and result using your example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This can also be used in OutJob file for Custom Folder Name for [Output Management](https://www.altium.com/documentation/17.1/display/ADES/((Preparing+Multiple+Outputs+in+an+OutputJob))_AD#!PreparingMultipleOutputsinanOutputJob-OutputLocation)

Answer (score 2):

Remark: For two word values its not working. These values have to be set in quotation marks. For example:

=Capacitance+'; '+"Voltage Rating"