# How to print several Project parameters combined on PCB in Altium Designer?

Tags: pcb-design, altium

Acording to questions

- [Can I combine Comment field from other Parameters in Altium Designer?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/369454/can-i-combine-comment-field-from-other-parameters-in-altium-designer) and
- [How to print value of variable on PCB into String feature in Altium Designer?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/373535/how-to-print-value-of-variable-on-pcb-into-string-feature-in-altium-designer)

I want to print values of [Project Parameter](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/WorkspaceManager_Dlg-ProjectPropertiesDialog_PageControl_Main_Parameters((Project+Options+-+Parameters))_AD) *Parameter1* and *Parameter2* on [String](https://www.altium.com/documentation/17.1/display/ADES/PCB_Dlg-ChangeString((String))_AD) feature on PCB, how to do this?

I firstly tried '.Parameter1+.Parameter2' and didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that needs quotation marks for every parameter

```
'.Parameter'
```

Therefore this works:

```
'.ParameterName1''.ParameterName2'
```